# Permission denied for transmission daemon event

Tags: transmission, groups, acl

I bit my teeth on this problem: I'm trying to set up `transmission-daemon` with an `incomplete` and `done` directory.
Downloading to `incomplete` does work fine, but for the `done` directory I receive a permission denied over and over again:

```
Feb 22 10:40:25 my-nas transmission-daemon[31244]: [2020-02-22 10:40:25.041] TORRENT tr_fdFileCheckout failed for "/srv/7e5e6032-1f1c-4efc-a74d-f3fe95fe606f/torrent/done/TORRENT/TORRENT_meta.sqlite.part": Permission denied (inout.c:102)
Feb 22 10:40:25 my-nas transmission-daemon[31244]: [2020-02-22 10:40:25.041] TORRENT Permission denied (/srv/7e5e6032-1f1c-4efc-a74d-f3fe95fe606f/torrent/done/TORRENT/TORRENT_meta.sqlite) (TORRENT.c:537)
```

Even though I have followed the instructions [like this](https://vroomtech.io/install-transmission-on-ubuntu-server/) and set up the right permissions for user `debian-transmission`.

These are the permissions for folder `incomplete` (to which I can download to):

```
$ getfacl incomplete
# file: incomplete
# owner: user
# group: debian-transmission
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:debian-transmission:rwx
user:user:rwx
group::rwx
group:mysql:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:debian-transmission:rwx
default:user:user:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:mysql:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

And for `done` (to which I can not download to):

```
$ getfacl done/
# file: done/
# owner: user
# group: debian-transmission
user::rwx
user:debian-transmission:rwx
user:user:rwx
user:stack:rwx
group::rwx
group:mysql:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:debian-transmission:rwx
default:user:user:rwx
default:user:stack:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:mysql:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

As far as I can tell user `debian-transmission` does have `rwx` permission? I'm not sure as I'm not 100% familiar with ACL's.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem (kind of) by installing a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/transmission/) of transmission. This does not run under user `debian-transmission` but with the `uid` of my normal user account (1000). Considering the docker image only has access to the `incomplete` and `done` folders I think it is safe enough.